# Creating Tidy Text

Tags: r, text, tidy

I am using R for text analysis. I used the 'readtext' function to pull in text from a pdf. However, as you can imagine, it is pretty messy. I used 'gsub' to replace text for different purposes. The general goal is to use one type of delimiter '*%%%%%*' to split records into rows, and another delimiter '@' into columns. I accomplished the first but am at a loss of how to accomplish the latter. A sample of the data found in the dataframe is as follows:

**895**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "The ambulatory case-mix development project\n@Published:: June 6, 1994@Authors: Baker A, Honigfeld S, Lieberman R, Tucker AM, Weiner JP@Country: United States @Journal:Project final report. Baltimore, MD, USA: Johns Hopkins University and Aetna Health Plans. Johns Hopkins\nUniversity and Aetna Health Plans, USA              As the US […"

**896**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "Ambulatory Care Groups: an evaluation for military health care use@Published:: June 6, 1994@Authors: Bolling DR, Georgoulakis JM, Guillen AC@Country: United States @Journal:Fort Sam Houston, TX, USA: United States Army Center for Healthcare Education and Studies, publication #HR 94-\n004. United States Army Center for Healthcare Education and […]@URL: http://oai.dtic.mil/oai/oai?verb=getRecord&metadataPrefix=html&identifier=ADA27804"

I want to take this data and split the @Published, @Authors, @Journal, @URL into columns -- c("Published", "Authors", "Journal", "URL").

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the fields *always* include those four fields? Do you want to discard the bit that comes before the first field?

Comment: This is very close but you will end up with 'Country:' etc.: `tidyr::separate(data.frame(txt), txt, c("Preamble","Published","Authors","Country","Journal"), sep="@") `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work OK:

```
dfr <- data.frame(TEXT=c("The ambulatory case-mix development project\n@Published:: June 6, 1994@Authors: Baker A, Honigfeld S, Lieberman R, Tucker AM, Weiner JP@Country: United States @Journal:Project final report. Baltimore, MD, USA: Johns Hopkins University and Aetna Health Plans. Johns Hopkins\nUniversity and Aetna Health Plans, USA As the US […",
"Ambulatory Care Groups: an evaluation for military health care use@Published:: June 6, 1994@Authors: Bolling DR, Georgoulakis JM, Guillen AC@Country: United States @Journal:Fort Sam Houston, TX, USA: United States Army Center for Healthcare Education and Studies, publication #HR 94-\n004. United States Army Center for Healthcare Education and […]@URL: http://oai.dtic.mil/oai/oai?verb=getRecord&metadataPrefix=html&identifier=ADA27804"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(magrittr)
do.call(rbind, strsplit(dfr$TEXT, "@Published::|@Authors:|@Country:|@Journal:")) %>%
as.data.frame %>%
setNames(nm = c("Preamble","Published","Authors","Country","Journal"))
```

Basically split the text by one of four fields (noticing double :: after Published!), row-binding the result, converting to a dataframe, and giving some names.